# List of open projects in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, project

Is there a way to have Eclipse return a list of open projects? I need Eclipse to provide me with a list of open projects within a plugin. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a call that returns just open projects so you would have to do something like:

```java
IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();

IProject [] projects = root.getProjects();

List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

for (IProject project : projects)
 {
    if (project.isOpen())
     {
        names.add(project.getName());

        // TODO handle open project
     }
 }
```

Comment: So is there a way to write the project names to a string or an array of strings with what you provided above?

Comment: Just call `project.getName()` to get the project name - see updated code